# Apache redirect location from new server to old

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

www.old-server.com/ws/ is the base URL for a web service on old-server. This is accomplished using a Location directive for "/ws" with a setHandler enclosed within the directive.

when a request for www.new-server.com/ws/ is received new-server needs to redirect the request to old-server/ws/. Any trailing parts of request URL need to be passed to old-server as well.

Running Apache2, with mod_rewrite.so loaded, on CentOS 7.

on new-server, the following does not work.

```
<Virtual Hosts>
...
    <Location /ws>
        Redirect "https://www.old-server/ $1"
    </Location>
...
</Virtual Hosts>
```

I think the doc's say Redirect is not support inside of Location.

What is the correct way to do redirect the request URL to old-server?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to stop over thinking the problem. The Location directive is fine, but my redirect statement was wrong. The following is working at the moment, pending further testing with more complex scenarios.

```
<Virtual Hosts>
...
    <Location /ws>
        Redirect "/ws" "https://www.old-server/ws"
    </Location>
...
</Virtual Hosts>
```